# Using same view for get, post and update request in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I am developing an mvc application in C# and facing an error **object reference not set to an Instance of an Object**, the data flow is as follows :-

1. For a GET request it returns a view and takes 2 input from user and POST request to controller to update 2 data fields below.
2. When returning the view, 2 fields are updated in same view using TempData

**View : (Name=ExpertUser)**

```
 // 2 User input fields
 <label>R 12.5 bend length:*</label>
 <input type="number" step="any" min="1" name="htlen" class="form-control fcus"/>
   @Html.Label("Select Diameter: *")
   <select name="diam" class="form-control fcus">
        <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
   </select>
 // 2 display fields to Update from controller
@{ var pno = TempData["partDetail"] as PartNo; }
@Html.Label("Total Watts :")@pno.htvotls   //<--Showing Error here for GET request
@Html.Label("Part No :") @pno.htvar   //<-- Showing Error
```

> The above view is has 4 fields, 2 fields for user input and 2 fields to update data

**Controller :**

```
 PartNo PartDetails = pno.PartNoCalc(htlen,diam);
 TempData["partDetail"] = PartDetails;
 return View("ExpertUser", "partDetail");
```

> PartNoCalc(htlen,diam) is function getting the details and storing the object in Tempdata
>
> The problem is that for the GET request the when view is called the pno calling the TempData is null

I am not using a strongly typed view as it cannot be integrated with Angular for UI render.
Thank you.

Comment: Always check if TempData["someValue"] has any value before using it, also try using ViewBag or ViewData as Tempdata is short lived and might produce unexpected results as in your case

Comment: Try using a viewbag and see if the issue goes away. as the Tempdata might be losing its data during a request, also when you say you are getting the same issue, is it still the reference not set? or is the value of the tempdata null?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have used ViewData and sert values to null and added few lines but same error.
 if (ViewData["partDetail"] == null || pno.Equals(null))
                                        {   pno = null;
                                            pno.htvotls = Convert.ToDecimal(null); }
                                    } @pno.htvotls

Comment: Do you mean the object not set to a reference error? did you check your stacktrace to see what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

try with this,hope it will be helpful for you

```
@{ var pno = TempData["partDetail"] as PartNo; }
@if (pno != null)
{
    @Html.Label("Total Watts :")@pno.htvotls
    @Html.Label("Part No :") @pno.htvar
}
```